# PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function msg_get_queue() in

Tags: php, apache, web

I'm trying to call the msg_get_queue() in a CentOS 64 bits server.

I've downloaded the php sources and i have compiled the pcntl extensions following the steps:

```
phpize
./configure
make
cp modules/* /usr/lib64/php/modules/
cp modules/* /usr/lib/php/modules/
```

When i run php -m the module appears in the list. Is there a way to solve this problem without compiling php with the --enable-sysvmsg?

Answer (score 0):

No, you must compile it with `--enable-sysvmsg`.